# Does Google counts backlinks from homepage to inside pages?

Tags: google, pagerank, backlinks

I have a site with good PR and my inside pages are getting increase of PR, but they don't have links pointing to them, only from my homepage.

Does that means that Google counts ALL links on my homepage, including links to inside pages?
Does it calculate inside pages PR with one coming from my domain, my homepage, too?

Also, if inside pages that got high PR from homepage have link back to homepage, will that increase homepage PR additionally, since those links should count too?

> By Google PR algorithm formula, by calculations on Wikipedia and
>   Stanford PR algorithm explanation ( which is originally developed by )
>   it counts those links, and also it counts after-increase backlink
>   again, making few times circle ( it stops because of d ( 0.85 ) factor. ), but it counts them.

Does anyone know is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every page that links to another page, is indexed by Google, and is not somehow blocking the flow of PageRank (I.e. nofollow) will pass PageRank to that page. The amount of PR will vary based on the PR of the linking page and the quantity of links on that page but PR will be passed. At one

Also point in time, when Google's index was much smaller, if you built a large enough website and interlinked your pages properly, you could launch your site with a PR of 7 without any incoming lixnks from external sites. (Remember PR is relative).

Also, Internal links count as votes just like incoming links from other websites. They're weighted less but still have value and can significantly influence your rankings.

As always, you should not be focusing on PR. It's worth for less than you think And focusing on it is a waste of your time.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Oh, I see now... Since Google calculates PR with `PR = ( 1 - d )/n + d(PRa/La+PRb/Lb+...)` In first part, ( 1 - d )/n is case when user randomly open your page over the all other pages ( n ), so when Google had few pages Ranked that n was smaller, and now it is bigger, so you get start up PR value very small, so backlinks from inside pages with that value doesn't count much... I know that, just **returning** backlinks are more interested to me... :) Why not focus on PR? Doesn't that make value of your site? Also, doesn't it effect position on Search Results?

Comment: PR used to be important in google's algorithm. It has *much* less value. So much less that is rarely is discussed anymore when talking about ranking factors. And PR only measure link popularity. Not page quality or site quality.

Answer (score 2):

PageRank flows within your own domain's internal links. Matt Cutts suggests you don't try and sculpt the page rank within your site by using nofollow or other methods. As you see pages on your site are getting PR based on the incoming links your home page has which in turn is linking to your sub pages. It's better though to try and get contextual links from other domains/pages on the web relevant to the pages they link to on your site and if they have PR all the better.

You can't expect to link from a sub page on your site back to the home page and built up your home pages PR like that even with thousands of sub pages it wont help in the SERP's as much as having links from other sites on the web.

Comment: Why he suggested that? Does Google bans for that or...?
Since I have some not useful inside pages and I want to remove them from following, and also since I can control all inside backlinks it can be useful to use them right way...

Answer (score 0):

Internal links does matter for high PR in Google. But i didn't find it useful to get traffic from Google. High PR does not mean Google will index it for better position. I have sites PR 3 but got less than 50 visitor daily.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is internal linking and therefore will be counted by Google. Most important point is that you find out how much power your different pages have and then to link from the page with a lot of power to the page that you want to push!

Comment: Why are you answering all these old questions? Not saying you can’t do that, but you are not adding anything new here.